# Un array de cadenas no mantiene los datos asignados

Tags: c

veréis, estoy con un ejercicio de la uni, básicamente me piden que calcule ciertas cosas de un triángulo partiendo de 3 puntos separados por `;` desde un archivo, de esta forma:

```
1 2 3;3 0 0;3 5 0
```

Hasta ahora tengo hechas un par de funciones para obtener en el main el número de líneas totales así como la línea con más caracteres.
Como para las operaciones que me piden necesitaré operar con las componentes de los puntos y vienen estructurados, mi idea es la de sacar en string separadas cada una de las líneas, para cortarlas y usar sus datos luego.

Intento hacer esto con la siguiente función, en la cuál aparece mi problema

```
void leerDatos(FILE *archivo, char *nombreArchivo, int lineas, int caracteres){
    char *matSalida[lineas];

    //Almacenamos para cada línea
    char *bufferAlmac = (char *)malloc(caracteres+1*sizeof(char));
    int k = 0;

    //Abrimos el archivo pasado por el argumento
    archivo=fopen(nombreArchivo,"r"); 

    //Comprobamos una buena apertura
    if(archivo==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error al abrir el archivo");  
    }

    //Alamacenamos todas las lineas como strings en un puntero
    while(fgets(bufferAlmac, caracteres+1, archivo) != NULL){
        matSalida[k] = bufferAlmac;
        printf("%s", matSalida[k]);
        k++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<lineas; i++){
        printf("%s", matSalida[i]);
    }

    //Liberamos y cerramos el archivo y su buffer de lectura
    free(bufferAlmac);
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

El problema está en el `printf("%s", matsalida[ ]);` ¿cuál? pues que el que está dentro del while funciona perfectamente e imprime el contenido que tenía `bufferAlmac` y supuestamente, el que tendrá esa posición k de matSalida; pero por el contrario, después del while, punto en el cuál se supone que ya tengo almacenadas todas las strings en las distintas posiciones de matSalida pues no imprime nada.

Muchas gracias por al ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

le hice unos arreglos a la funcion "leerDatos" que expones en tu pregunta y ahora funciona bien, la instruccion `matSalida[k] = bufferAlmac;` la he cambiado por `strcpy(matSalida[k],bufferAlmac);` ademas el limite de iteraciones del ciclo for con el que muestras los strings guardados, no debe ser la variable "lineas" sino que, lo correcto es la variable "k" pueto que es el que tiene el numero de ciclos que ejecuto while, lo que equivale a la cantidad de strings que fueron almacenados en tu array de punteros tipo char `char *matSalida[lineas];` y por ultimo en la parte de la comprobacion le agregue un argumento mas al fprintf, tal que asi `fprintf(stderr,"- Error al abrir el archivo: %s\n",strerror(errno));` "strerror" de la libreria <string.h> muetra los errores mas comunes indicado por "errno" a la hora de manejar ficheros, errno pertenece a la libreria <errno.h>

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void leerDatos(FILE *archivo, char *nombreArchivo, int lineas, int caracteres){
    char *matSalida[lineas];

    //Almacenamos para cada línea
    char *bufferAlmac = (char *)malloc((caracteres+1)*sizeof(char));
    int k = 0;

    //Abrimos el archivo pasado por el argumento
    archivo=fopen(nombreArchivo,"rt"); 

    //Comprobamos una buena apertura
    if(archivo==NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"- Error al abrir el archivo: %s\n",strerror(errno));
      return; 
    }

    //Alamacenamos todas las lineas como strings en un puntero
    while(fgets(bufferAlmac, caracteres+1, archivo) != NULL){
        strcpy(matSalida[k],bufferAlmac);
        printf("%s", matSalida[k]);
        k++;
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
        printf("%s", matSalida[i]);
    }

    //Liberamos y cerramos el archivo y su buffer de lectura
    free(bufferAlmac);
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es interesante porque este tipo de error de no hacer asignaciones correctamente me ha pasado varias veces